# vs2010 Cache SQL data incorrect fields

Tags: c#, types

OK, I found a walkthrough on msdn for what I was after (offline database cache). However when I let the wizard create a local database from my online sql server the timespan fields are converted to a string??

Now I know the suggestion was to create my own local database and then use the MS Synch framework...however...this proclaims to do it "out of the box"

However now I've a dataset which I've no idea how to use, and a database newly formed (for the synched cache) taht I will have to use Ling to Entities with(??)

meanwhile I have this weird timespan to string conversion?

should I give up now or push on?

can i overwrite the the .designer.cs? typeof(string) to typeof(timespan)?

damn wizards!!

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy...I was missing the connection strings, since I was trying to access the data through the test project  8(

Linq to Entities now working fine (seems I couldn't use link to sql with my local data.sdf?

slipped the app.config over & whammo...data... But now I still have the field mismatch to deal with